# How to pass a value to my parent React component from input type?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this in my parent `TodoList` component:

```
state = {
  checkedIds: []
}
_handleSelectedTodo = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault(); 
  this.setState({checkedIds: [...this.state.checkedIds, e.value]});
}
```

the `_handleSelectedTodo` is passed as props to `Todo` component like this

```
<Todo
  key={edge.node.id}
  todo={edge.node}
  viewer={this.props.viewer}
  handleSelectedTodo={this._handleSelectedTodo}
/>
```

Now below is the code of my `Todo` component:

```
<li>
  <input
    checked={this.props.todo.complete}
    className="toggle"
    onChange={this.props.handleSelectedTodo.bind(null)}
    type="checkbox"
    value={this.props.todo.id}
  /> 
  {this.props.todo.text+' - '+this.props.todo.complete}
```

I want to pass the value here to parent as `e.target.value` but I cannot succeed changing the state of my `TodoList` parent `checkedIds`. Help?

Comment: Try removing `.bind(null)` and using `e.target.value` instead of `e.value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first it should be `e.target.value` instead of `e.value`

```
_handleSelectedTodo = (e) => {
  // here add your logic for update the completed flag depending on the value of the id 
  this.setState({checkedIds: [...this.state.checkedIds, e.target.value]});
}
```

to pass the callback is without bind (since you already used arrow function in todoList)

```
<input
    checked={this.props.todo.complete}
    className="toggle"
    onChange={this.props.handleSelectedTodo}
    type="checkbox"
    value={this.props.todo.id}
  />
```

additionally, I think you still need to handle when checkbox is unchecked (removed from the array)

https://codepen.io/kossel/pen/XRZPdK

Comment: this works but my component doesn't update if it's checked, even if the props is already checked, I tried componentWillMount but doesn't work?

Comment: if you mean the check mark doesnt get updated it will depends on where you save the "checked state" the `complete` flag

Answer (score 0):

Child

```
<input type="text" onChange={event => this.props.onInputChange(event.target.value)}/>
```

Parent

```
onInputChange(filter){
    console.log(filter)
  }


<child onInputChange ={this.onInputChange.bind(this)}/>
```

Comment: Can you add some explenation to your answerr? Only showing code can be confusing.